# Upload File using Async-HTTP

Tags: php, android, post

im trying to upload a file, it say SUCCESS but the file does not come to the server..

my java:

```
File file = new File(Constantes.getLeiFileFullPath(texto.getID()));
                    RequestParams parms = new RequestParams();
                    try {
                        parms.put("file", file);
                    } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
                        e.printStackTrace();
                    }
                    AsyncHttpClient client = new AsyncHttpClient();
                    client.post("http://myserver.net/up.php", parms, new AsyncHttpResponseHandler() {
                        @Override
                        public void onSuccess(int statusCode, Header[] headers, byte[] responseBody) {
                            Log.d("POSTFILE", "SUCESSU " + statusCode);
                        }

                        @Override
                        public void onFailure(int statusCode, Header[] headers, byte[] responseBody, Throwable error) {
                            Log.d("POSTFILE", "FAILURE");
                        }

                    });
```

and the PHP:

```
<?php

/* Insira aqui a pasta que deseja salvar o arquivo*/
$uploaddir = "uploads/";

$uploadfile = $uploaddir . $_FILES['file']['name'];

if (move_uploaded_file($_FILES['file']['tmp_name'], $uploadfile)){
echo "Arquivo Enviado";}
else {echo "Arquivo não enviado";}

?>
```

whats it wrong that it doesnt create the file but say "SUCCESS"?

Comment: Better look at responseBody parameter. As there is nothing in your php script that causes for a statusCode. You also do not mention the respinseCode.

Comment: grenapps the response code is 200, does that put("file", file) has to do something with this  $_FILES['file']['name'];